# How to define if an index is too large?

Tags: python, list

```
#Write your function here
def double_index(lst, index):
  lst[index] = lst[index]*2
  return lst

print(double_index([3, 8, -10, 12], 2))
```

It works and prints what is expected but it says "make sure to define what should happen if index is too big".
Any suggestions?

Comment: Use an `if` block. Do you know how to get the length of a list?

Comment: Do you mean if the index greater than the length of list?

Comment: Hi, sorry I might've not made it clear. It states that if index is not a valid index, then it should return the original list? I'm unsure what it means by a valid index. I assumed it meant a negative indice but the answer is a negative number as it should be -20 ?

Comment: an invalid index is any index that would cause an error. For example, try `double_index([3, 8, -10, 12], 4)`. Negative indices can actually be valid. Try `double_index([3, 8, -10, 12], -1)`

Comment: valid index for a list is either `len(l)-1` (positive index) or `-len(l)` (negative index) (_where `l` is the list_)

Comment: Oh I understand now, so obvious haha. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The question is expecting you to check if the provided index is valid.
By valid it means the index should be present in the list.

Try this :

```
#Write your function here
def double_index(lst, index):
  if index < len(lst) and index >= -len(lst):
     lst[index] = lst[index]*2
  return lst

print(double_index([3, 8, -10, 12], 2))
```

To understand take this example :

- you have a list [3,8,-10, 12]
- if you print the value at index 0,1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,-4 you will get some value.
- If you try to print the value at any other index, eg: 10, -8, 5 it will give index error. This means the index is not valid for this list.